# Oracle: Create function that returns multiple rows

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have created a  type inside a package and declared a function as below.

```
type backupStatus_t is table of d_backupstatus%ROWTYPE;
```

```
function getLatestBackupInfo return backupStatus_t;
```

Now, inside the package body, I have defined the function as below.

```
function getLatestBackupInfo RETURN backupStatus_t as
      v_backupStatus backupStatus_t;
      begin
        select * bulk collect into v_backupStatus from d_backupstatus;
        return v_backupStatus;
      end;
```

Package compiles successfully.
When I try to call this function, I am getting "invalid datatype".

Can anyone help??

Comment: Please **edit your question** and show example code where you're trying to call this function. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe the problem you want to solve and DB version you use. PL/SQL types are not known to SQL. But if you really want to return dataset from a function, you may consider SQL macro or pipelined function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your "backupStatus_t" type outside of your package, like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE backupStatus_t AS TABLE OF d_backupstatus%ROWTYPE;
```

Comment: Good approach, but `d_backupstatus%ROWTYPE` needs the PL/SQL compiler so won't work in SQL.